# trying to upload data to DynamoDB. Although I am not receiving any error messages, the data is not being uploaded to the database as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Question:
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to upload data from a MySQL database to DynamoDB using the AWS SDK. Although there are no error messages, the data is not being uploaded to DynamoDB as expected. I've followed the AWS documentation and reviewed my code thoroughly, but I'm unable to identify the root cause of the problem. Here's a breakdown of my scenario:

Context:
I'm building a project that involves migrating data from a MySQL database to DynamoDB. The goal is to fetch data from the MySQL table and insert it into the corresponding DynamoDB table. Both databases are set up correctly, and I have confirmed the connectivity.

```
const Database  = require("./database");
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

async function fetchMySQLData() {
    const db = new Database();
    const connection = db.getConnection();
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM xyztable limit 5;';
    const result = await db.query(query);

    const dynamoDBItems = result.map(row => ({
        PutRequest: {
            Item: {
                PK: { S: `AppsAli#ID` }, // PK format: TableNameid
                SK: { S: `AppsAli#${row.ID}`}, 
            }
        }
        
    }));


    const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();
    const tableName = 'xyz';

    const batchWriteParams = {
        RequestItems: {
            [tableName]: dynamoDBItems
        }
    };

    try {
        const data = await dynamoDB.batchWriteItem(batchWriteParams).promise();
        console.log('Success Items deployed to DynamoDB', data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error', err);
    }

    connection.end();
    return { result };
}

module.exports = {
    fetchMySQLData
}
```

Comment: It may be useful to you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

Answer (score 0):

You parameters for `BatchWriteItem` are completely wrong:

```
  const batchWriteParams = {
        RequestItems: {
            [tableName]: dynamoDBItems
        }
    };
```

Parameters should look like this:

```
{
   "RequestItems": { 
      "YourTableName" : [ 
            "PutRequest": { 
               "Item": { 
                  // Your first item values
               }
            }, 
            "PutRequest": { 
               "Item": { 
                  // Your second item values
               }
            }
            ...
            ...
      ]
   },
   "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "string",
   "ReturnItemCollectionMetrics": "string"
}
```

More info in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#API_BatchWriteItem_RequestSyntax)